# Expressjs save function doesn't save user changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create route for changing password, and this is what I tried and it doesn't work. I got a success, but password don't change.

```
router.put("/:username/change-password", function(req, res) {
  User
    .findOne({
      username: req.params.username
    }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "Nema usera."
        })
      } else {
        user.comparePassword(req.body.oldPassword, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (!isMatch) return res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Stara lozinka nije ispravna."
          })

          if (req.body.newPassword) {
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.newPassword, salt);
            user.password = hash;
            user.save((err, user) => {
              if (err) return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: "There was a problem updating the user."
              });
              res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: "Success updating user.",
              });
            });
          }

        })
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  What debugging did you do?  Did you trace through your request handler and follow all the values to see what you were putting in the user object?  Did you check the database to see if the new password was there in the database?  Did you flush your session and require a relogin?  Do `req.body.oldPassword` and `req.body.newPassword` contain the correct values?

Comment: I've checked new hashed password is good, i've checked if it's stored in database and it isn't updated.

Comment: Is your schema correct? Could you also share it here?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the above code..

Comment: Can you try to save this like user.password = 1 that is before user.save() function and see if 1 is saved in db or not??

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: Password is still the same, so save function doesnt save it to the user